# I dont add a records to the store ExtJS

Tags: extjs, store

ExtJs 6.2

```
    var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store"); 

    var dep = {dd:11};

    store.add({dd:11});
    store.add(dep);
    store.add(dep);
    store.add(dep); 
    store.add(dep);
    store.add(dep);
    store.add(dep);
    store.add(dep);
    store.add({dd:11});
    console.log("Count:" + store.count());
```

**Count:3**

A variable object is added only once.
**Why?????**

Comment: Could you please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question. Can you also provide a meaningful title for the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind this is that `store.add` is not pure function meaning it changes `dep` so after first add `dep` no longer holds reference to a simple javascript object but instead it is a reference to added model. After that you are trying to add model that is already in a store so it is omitting it

You can verify this by doing `console.log` of a `def` variable after first add

Wokaround:

```
store.add(Ext.clone(dep));
```